# Can we customize the input type number in HTML5?

Tags: html, number-formatting

We want input type number to have the min and max values to take 001 and 009 (with leading zeros) as values in the input box.Is there a way to customize it?

Comment: might not be possible by only using html5, you can try type text with pattern attribute plus some css to achieve the desired behavior

Comment: Could you send me the code if you can.Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a "write for me" service web site. Have you tried anything, have you looked for something? have you done any research before?

Comment: Not very elegant but see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oddFeb/1j3cqrLm/2/#&togetherjs=tMUHq0QlwO)